# Xamarin button no border

Tags: xaml, xamarin

How can I remove the border outside buttons? I've two buttons, and I want them to be next to each other, without borders and margins.

I've tried to set property BorderWidth and WidthRequest etc, but it doesn't have any impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you're getting a spacing between the buttons because of the parent layout. If you have the buttons inside a `StackLayout`, try to set `StackLayout.Spacing` property to 0.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
</StackLayotu>
```

For a `Grid` use the `RowSpacing` and the `ColumnSpacing` properties.